# Filling a unit cube with countable balls.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

> Is it possible to fill an $n-$dimensional unit cube with countable number of non-overlapping $n-$dimensional balls?

By $n-$dimensional unit cube, I am thinking of the set
$$
C:=\{\ x\in\Bbb R^n\ |\ 0\le x_i\le 1\ \text{for all}\ i=1,2,\dots,n\ \}
$$
where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. An $n-$dimensional ball centered at $x_0$ is defined to be
$$
B(x_0;r):=\{\ x\in\Bbb R^n\ |\ d(x_0,x)<r\ \}
$$ 
where $d$ is the Euclidean distance function.

> A sequence of balls $(B_1,B_2,\dots)$ is said to **fill** the unit cube if they are *pairwise-disjoint*, each $B_i\subset C$ and
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_i)=1
> $$ 
>   where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$.

Intuitively, I feel that it should be possible to fill the unit cube with many balls. However, I can't think of a way to prove it.

Since $C$ is separable, I thought about enumerating its rational points into a sequence $\{c_1,c_2,c_3,\dots \}$ and form balls around them such that $B_i:=B(c_i,r_i)$ where
$$
r_i:=\sup\{\ r\in\Bbb R^+\ |\ B(c_i;r)\ \text{is contained in $C$ and doesn't intersect $B_1,B_2,\dots,B_{i-1}$} \}.
$$ 
I don't know if this method works or not. I would really appreciate if anyone can suggest a way to finish the prove, suggest a new method, or give a negative answer to my question. An answer that only works in dimension $2$ or $3$ is also very welcomed.

Comment: Note that your method fails for a more trivial (and very fixable) reason:  At some point you will get to a $c_i$ that is already inside a ball, and then there will be no $r_i$ that works. The other reason it might fail is that even though every point in the countable, dense subset is surrounded by a positive radius ball doesn't mean that every point in the cube is inside one. To see how this is even possible, take the rationals in $(0,1)$, allow the balls (intervals) to overlap, but fix the radius to $1/2^{i+1}$. Then the total length of all the balls will be $1/2$, so $[0,1]$ is not covered.

Comment: @Arthur When $c_i$ is inside some already existing ball, $r_i$ is merely 0 so $B_i$ is basically an empty set. I thought about your second point as well and the fat Cantor set immediately came to my mind so I didn't allow the radius of each ball to be arbitrary. I thought that using supremum might fix the issue but I still cannot finish the prove.

Comment: It also seems to me that something that can be written as the union of disjoint opens can't be connected

Comment: @YannHamdaoui: The balls don't have to cover all of $C$, they just have to have measure $1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  First, let me set up a bit of machinery.  Define a *dyadic cube* to be an open cube of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{a_i}{2^k},\frac{a_i+1}{2^k}\right)$ where $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$.  Write $N\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ for the set of points which have at least one coordinate that is a dyadic rational; note that $N$ has measure $0$.  Note that if $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $x\in U\setminus N$, there is a dyadic cube $D$ such that $x\in D\subseteq U$ (since if $x\not\in N$ then there are dyadic cubes of arbitrarily small diameter containing $x$).  Moreover, there is a maximal such cube.  It follows that $U\setminus N$ is contained in the union of all the maximal dyadic cubes contained in $U$.  Moreover, these maximal dyadic cubes are disjoint, since if two dyadic cubes intersect then one must be contained in the other.

To sum up, we have shown that if $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open, there is a (necessarily countable) disjoint union of dyadic cubes contained in $U$ that has full measure in $U$.

Now let us consider your question.  Start by picking any ball $B\subset C$.  Let $U=C\setminus \overline{B}$.  As above, we can partition almost all of $U$ into dyadic cubes.  We can then choose scaled down versions of $B$ inside each of these dyadic cubes, and repeat: take the complement of the closures of these balls inside each dyadic cube, and partition almost all of those sets into dyadic cubes.  We then take scaled down versions of $B$ inside all these new dyadic cubes, and so on.

At each step of this process, we add new balls which take up $\mu(B)/\mu(C)$ of the measure we have not yet covered with balls.  Thus the measure not covered by balls after $N$ steps is $(1-\mu(B)/\mu(C))^N$.  This converges to $0$, so after iterating infinitely many times we have "filled" $C$.

More generally, a similar argument shows that if $B\subset C$ is any set of positive measure such that $\mu(B)=\mu(\overline{B})$, then $C$ can be "filled" by scaled copies of $B$.

Comment: This is very interesting thank you! My internet connection is quite poor at the moment so the LaTeX parts aren't rendered properly. I'll read it as soon as possible.

Comment: This answer is beautiful! May I ask you what are some other interesting applications of dyadic cubes? It seems that this idea has a wide range of applicable topics in various area.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add some remarks besides the elegant proof by Eric Wofsey.

[Vitali's covering theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma#Vitali.27s_covering_theorem_for_the_Lebesgue_measure) implies that not only you can do it, but also that you can use balls from any given family $\mathcal{V}=\{B_j\}_{j\in J}$, provided it is a *Vitali covering* of your set (this means that any point $x\in C$ is contained in balls with arbitrarily small radius).

Moreover the same is true with minor modifications for any Radon measure, if you consider a family of *closed* balls (obviously this is irrelevant for the Lebesgue measure). To prove this result however you need a different covering theorem, namely [Besicovitch's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besicovitch_covering_theorem). You can see for instance the first chapter of the book by Evans and Gariepy, *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions*.

The first linked Wikipedia article also states a version with balls replaced by any family of sets which are not "too thin", meaning that
$$\mathrm{diam}(B)^n\leq C \mathcal{L}^n(B)$$ 
for any set $B$ in the family (this is closely related to the last paragraph in the answer by Eric).

It would be really interesting to know if your proposed algorithm works. I've thought about it some time but I didn't go anywhere for now.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will surely take a look at this.