# Every open $n-cube$ is a countable disjoint union of open balls plus a zero set?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, inequality, lebesgue-measure

This is a homework question and I have been attempting it for a while. The problem is from the book "Real Mathematical Analysis" by Charles Pugh, Chapter 6 #4.

The question is asking for a generalization of a lemma in 2-dim to n-dim. The content of the lemma is stated in the title (n=2) and the "insight" was that a square $S$ contains a disk $\Delta$ such that $m\Delta / mS > 1/2$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

I am thinking of a corresponding inequality in n-dim, and I feel I should try proving $m\Delta / mS > 1/n$, where $S$ is the n-dim cube ($(-R, R)^n$) and $\Delta$ should be the n-ball with radius $R$.

I looked up the volume [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#High_dimensions) for n-ball, and think I should try showing the two inequalities (if my guess is right):

$n = 2k: V_{2k}(R) / (2R)^{2k} = (\frac{\pi}{4})^k \frac{1}{k!} > \frac{1}{2k}$

$n = 2k+1: V_{2k+1}(R) / (2R)^{2k+1} = \frac{\pi ^k k!}{(2k+1)!} > \frac{1}{2k+1}$

For the $n=2k$ case, I tried grouping the LHS as $\Pi_{i=1}^{k} (\frac{1}{i} \frac{\pi}{4})$ but found that $\Pi_{i=2}^{k} (\frac{1}{i} \frac{\pi}{4}) < \frac{1}{k}$, though when $i=1$ the term is greater than 1/2. I am stuck and do not know where to start, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might, or might not, just be simpler to show ever n-ball contains an complete n cube in it, and every n-cube contains a complete n-ball in it.  Then argue why that makes the statement equivalent whether we are talking balls or cubes.  Then show it for cubes, which is really easy.  All that calculation of area... 1) it's hard, 2) it's futzing, and 3) in big picture it's utterly irrelevent 4) you are eventually going to have to show it for all measurable connected shapes anyway, ovoids, tetrahedrons, blobs...

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of "equivalent metrics".  If you replace the euclidean "straight line" metric with the "taxicab" or "sum of change in each axis" metric, "balls" become cubes, and it's very easy.

Comment: @Yang: Firstly, your attempt to prove $\small{\displaystyle{\frac{V_{2k}(R)}{(2R)^{2k}} > \frac{1}{2k}}}$ is doomed, since for large $k$, $\small{\displaystyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^k \frac{1}{k!}}}$  is dramatically less than $\small{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2k}}}$. Similarly, your attempted inequality for the odd case is also doomed.

Comment: @Yang: But if I understand the author's $2$D proof correctly, all you need is that for each $n$, there is _some_ positive lower bound, depending on $n$, but independent of $R$, for the ratio of the volume of the $n$-ball to the volume of the enclosing $n$-cube. So you don't even need to compute it. Just call it something, $c$ say, and use it in the same way that the constant $1/2$ was used for the $2$D argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1881977/filling-a-unit-cube-with-countable-balls

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What does the title have to do with the body text?